# Are there any software to use notebook screen as second monitor?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have my desktop PC running Windows 7 and Acer netbook running Windows XP and I want to use its screen as second monitor for my desktop via LAN. Are there any software to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is a exact dupe or not, so am going to answer...

[MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/) is what you're looking for...cost $40 for a license, though.

OR, you could enable keyboard and mouse sharing between computers.  Check out this webpage from Alternativeto.com...it lists the (mostly) free alternatives to Maxivista...as good of a list as you're gonna get...

http://alternativeto.net/desktop/maxivista/